# How to make keras extract features from the image

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a list of images as training data, where one image looks like this:

[image]

For every training image, I manually labelled the red fibre and generated
a grayscale image which looks like this:

[image]

Now I want the algorithm to learn the red fibre labelling process
and for each image return a grayscale image:

```
def readImagesIntoNumpy(directory):
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    images = map(lambda file: io.imread(directory + file), files)
    return np.array(images)

// xTrain.shape = (num_of_images, 256, 256, 4)
xTrain = readImagesIntoNumpy("./original/")
// yTrain.shape = (num_of_images, 256, 256, 1)
yTrain = np.expand_dims(readImagesIntoNumpy("./gray/"), axis = 3)

// constructing the neural network
s = Input((256, 256, 4))
o = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation = 'sigmoid')(s)
for i in range(20):
    o = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='elu')(o)
o = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation = 'sigmoid')(o)
model = Model(inputs = [s], outputs = [o])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
// model.summary() has 21313 trainable parameters

// training the neural network:
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs = 50, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

However, if I now make the model predict the grayscale image on the training data

```
yPredicted = model.predict(xTrain)
```

it returns only completely black images.

**Why?**

Comment: Maybe your plotting library doesn't support plotting between 0 and 1? Try plotting the image `*255`. Also, make sure you've got good metrics. Most of the images is black indeed and black images have good results.

Comment: @DanielMöller changing the metrics helped, thanks.

Comment: @prosti you want me to email you the training and test .png files, is that what you want?